# jQuery form submission when form nested in table

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Is there a reason why forms won't submit using jQuery inside tables or am I just doing something wrong? I've tested the form submission outside a table, then soon as i wrapped it inside a table it stopped working, even though I added an extra `parent()` to make up for the form moving above the `<td>` element within the code. Could anybody be able to help me out with this issue please?

**HTML**

```
WITHOUT TABLE
<form action="page.cfm" method="post">
    <select class="select">
        <option>Test</option>
    </select>
</form>

WITH TABLE
<table>
    <tr>
        <form action="page.cfm" method="post">
            <td>
                <select class="select">
                    <option>Test</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
WITHOUT TABLE
$(".select").on("change", function() {
    $(this).parent("form").submit();
});

WITH TABLE
$(".select").on("change", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: Wild guess, TD is not a valid child of a form, and a form isn't really a valid child of a TR.

Comment: Having `form` as a child element of `tr` is not a valid HTML.

Comment: As pointed down below, invalid HTML is not incorrect HTML. Most website don't stick with valid HTML, however i do understand that it is best to try stick to as much valid HTML as possible so i appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Know this is an older post -- and from someone who still believes that <table> elements have their place in website design -- ran across this same issue, and with no more elegant choice, replaced <table> elements with <div> elements (using Bootstrap layout) and was able to get similar layout with that approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a reason why forms won't submit using jQuery inside tables or am I just doing something wrong?

Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org). A form can contain an entire table. A form can be contained entirely in a table cell. A form cannot contain only *some* cells that make up a table.

Error correction in the browser is putting the form outside the table, so trying to submit it gives unexpected results.

Comment: invalid HTML doesn't mean incorrect HTML. However, i do understand your point. My issue is the table will contain an update and remove button, requiring two different forms, so does this mean i need a form per cell for each action?

Comment: "invalid HTML doesn't mean incorrect HTML" — yes, it does (although the reverse isn't necessarily true).

Comment: Yes, you need a form per cell.

Comment: Bugger, cheers for filling me in though. And i'm pretty sure it doesn't, or a lot of websites would not be working if all the HTML was incorrect.

Comment: "incorrect" does not mean "so bad that web browsers are unable to recover" (but being correct saves a lot of time trying to figure out why something looks wrong in one or more browsers)

Comment: True, true. I understand what you are saying in all fairness as I have just done a little research and perhaps I was wrong, as in the case of modern technology such as mobile and tablets things can go wrong. Interesting read actually I perhaps need to look into this more.

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<form action="page.cfm" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="select">
                    <option>Test</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(".select").on("change", function() {
    this.form.submit();
});
```

note that for form elements `this.form` references the containing form.

Comment: My issue is that I can update more than one cell, but within the same table there needs to be a different form for me to remove the item from the table. This is why I was nesting `<td>'s` inside of form elements.

Comment: @LeeB - you can just nest the entire table inside the form ?

Comment: As I said i would, but the removal of the product from the table requires a separate form as one of the values for that is different from the value for updating. I'm going to find a solution anyway now that i understand the reason.

Answer (score 0):

### Try using `$.closest()`

WITHOUT/WITH TABLE

```
$(".select").on("change", function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```