# Multiple forms on one page how to know which form was submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I use the following code to render rows. Each row is one form:

```
foreach (var j in m.List)
{
   using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "myForm" }))
   {
      <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="@j.UserId.ToString()" />
      <input type="hidden" name="jobId" value="@j.JobId.ToString()" />
      <select name="statusId" class="selectField">
         <option value="-1">...
   }
}
```

When I change `status` I make an AJAX call:

```
$('select[name="statusId"]').on('change', function () {
                $('.myForm').triggerHandler('submit');
            });
            $(".myForm").on("submit", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var url = $(this).attr("action");
                var formData = $(this).serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });

            });
```

The problem is I don't get selected form values in my function:

```
public ActionResult Action(int userId, int statusId, int jobid)
```

But always get values for the first rendered form on the page. Why?

```
    <tbody>
<form action="/Controller/Action" class="myForm" method="post">                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="#">...</a></td>
                                            <td><a href="#">...</a></td>
                                            <td><a href="#">...</a></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="2" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="jobId" value="31" />
                                                <select name="statusId" class="selectField">
                                                    <option value="-1">A</option>
                                                    <option value="1">B</option>
                                                    <option value="2">C</option>
                                                </select>    
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
</form><form ...
```

Comment: Can you post some of the rendered HTML? Is the page still posting when you click a submit button? What's inside the request?

Comment: Your javascript is triggering the submit of every form with a class of `myForm` when changing any select element with a name of `statusId`.. you need to look for the relevant parent form instead.

Comment: Can you post answer with example how can I find  parent form of selected dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. You're always submitting the first form (possibly all forms).
2. Your HTML is invalid. [`<forms>` cannot be inside of a `<table>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17921759/1445356), so jQuery does not traverse that as you would like.

### Solutions

1. You need to get the correct form to submit, that is a parent of the `<select>` field that changed.

   Use the following JavaScript:

   ```
   $('select[name="statusId"]').on('change', function () {
       $(this).parents('.myForm').triggerHandler('submit');
   });
   ```
2. Either move the form to outside of the table completely, or switch to using `<div>` and `<ul><li>`s.
   Unfortunately this may require a fair bit a work for you to fix, but invalid HTML will be an ongoing problem in everything you attempt. [You can validate you HTML here](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

**[jsFiddle using ul/li](http://jsfiddle.net/Kt5zq/)**

**[jsFiddle using table inside form](http://jsfiddle.net/V39GF/)**

Comment: When I put this nothing happens? No error just nothing happens when I change index.

Answer (score 0):

The first portion of your script will trigger submit of all forms with class `myForm`. To avoid this, add the handler to the closest `myForm`, so only that one will get submitted.

```
$('select[name="statusId"]').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('.myForm').triggerHandler('submit');
});
```

Comment: Nothing happens. Same like in @arsebin3 answer.

Comment: So nothing happens at all? If you set a breakpoint in the anonymous function you pass to jquery's `.on()` are they hit? Are these forms being added to the DOM after the initial page load?