# jquery $.post fails to send data on second request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a bunch of records from a database that I am displaying on a page. Each record has their own form with an update and delete button. I'm using JQuery ajax to send the data to a PHP page to process the form.

The script works fine the first time I push any one of the buttons on any of the forms, but when I push another button on any of the forms (or even the same button on the same form) the ajax request doesn't send any of the data to the PHP page.

Code I'm using to output data on page:

```
<?php
foreach($records as $data) {
?>      
        <form>
            <input type="number" name="et" step="0.01" value="<?php echo $data->et; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $data->et_id; ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
        </form>
<?php
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var buttonName;

    $('input[type=submit]').click('click', function() {
        buttonName = $(this).attr('name');
    });

    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var values = $(this).serializeArray();
        console.log(values);

        if(buttonName == 'delete') {
            var message = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?\n\n You can\'t get it back once you do.');
        } else {
            message = true;
        }

        if(message) {
            $.post('submit/raw_et.php', {et: values[0].value, token: values[1].value, id: values[2].value, button: buttonName}, function(r) {
                console.log(r);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PHP Snippet:

```
echo $_POST['button'];
echo $_POST['et'];
echo $_POST['id'];
```

The "values" variable in the javascript always has the correct data, but the ajax fails to send any data after the first time a button is pushed and the results return blank.

I don't understand why it won't send the data. Am I missing something really easy, or is it something more complicated?

**Edit:**
I've taken out the tables in the html, but still get the same results.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921647/jquery-form-submission-when-form-nested-in-table

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use a validator: http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element

Comment: I tried it without tables and it still does the same thing.

Comment: Html validation for data?!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are developing in a completely wrong pattern, instead of defining form inside tr, use record id and register event for clicking buttons:

```
<?php
foreach($records as $data) {
?>      
    <tr>

            <td><input type="number" name="et" step="0.01" value="<?php echo $data->et; ?>" /></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $data->et_id; ?>"/>
            <td><a class='edit' meta-id="<?php echo $record; ?>">edit</a></td>
            <td><a class='delete' meta-id="<?php echo $record; ?>">delete</a></td>

    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

And now, try to register all buttons onclick for delete and edit.

```
$(".edit").click(function() {
    var record = $(this).attr("meta-id"); 
    $.post("edit uri" , {record : record , otherparam: valueofit} , function(result) {
          alert(result);
    }); 
});


$(".delete").click(function() {
    var record = $(this).attr("meta-id"); 
    $.post("delte uri" , {record : record} , function(result) {
          alert(result);
    }); 
});
```

You can expand the concept as you want, for less adding class to buttons or so on.